# WPF: HorizontalAlignment=Stretch, MaxWidth, and Right aligned at the same time?

Tags: wpf, alignment, stretch, dockpanel

More or less the same question like here, but right align: [HorizontalAlignment=Stretch, MaxWidth, and Left aligned at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280331/wpf-horizontalalignment-stretch-maxwidth-and-left-aligned-at-the-same-time)

How do I get this blue text box to grow with the size of the window, have a maximum width of 200 pixels, and be right justified?

This is what I have, but it's centered instead of right aligned. Why?

```
   <DockPanel Background="LightSteelBlue">
        <TextBox Margin="3 3 3 3" DockPanel.Dock="Right" MaxWidth="200" />
    </DockPanel>
```

Comment: why don t u use the result of the answer you posted and replace left by right...

Comment: Use Snoop to see if really the textbox is wrong layouted, or maybe the panels and controls above it.

Comment: Why downvoted? I tried the answers in the linked question, but it's not working like expected. Because I use a margin, I cannot simply bind to the actual width of the container. The container is allways 6 pixels more wide than the texbox itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets answer my own question. This works, but it's not an example of nice code. There must be a  much better solution.

```
<Grid Background="LightSteelBlue">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1000*" MaxWidth="200"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox Margin="3 3 3 3" Grid.Column="1"  />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: the best solution is to move to another UI framework